# Enable compiler warnings in Kdevelop

Tags: makefile, g++, kdevelop

I'm using Kdevelop for a simple C++ project. I know that Kdevelop uses CMake to build the project, but the only thing that I known about CMake is that if I add a new `.cpp` source file in my project, I have to add it also in `CMakeLists.txt`.

Now I'm trying to enable tha `gcc` compiler warnings (i.e. compiling with `g++ -Wall ...`).

Does Kdevelop have a compiler settings section, or I have to edit directly the `Makefile` or another CMake settings file?

Comment: Solved by creating a new project using a personal Makefile. Indeed if I am not able to use CMake, the simplest solution is not to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add compiler flags in CMake by adding the following command to your CMakeLists.txt:

```
list( APPEND CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall")
```

Comment: You probably mean `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall")`, because `list(APPEND XYZ "${XYZ} ABC")` not only is excessive, but does not actually work (no idea why).